# write unique values column pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with different data:

| Ordernumber | Name | customerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Abel | 1939184849 |
|  | Rose | 1029480129 |
|  | Rob | 1283949203 |

As you can see the name and customerID are already filled in.
Now I need to generate unique ordernumbers, please keep in mind that the actual database has around 20,000 rows, so the ordernumber has to be unique.

Comment: define "generate"

Comment: Write unique integers in column order number.

Comment: Do you mind showing example of expected output

Answer (score 1):

Can it be only numbers? i.e. ranging from 0 to the total length of your dataframe?

```
df['Ordernumber'] = [n for n in range(0,len(df),1)]
```